# Is there setClientBoundingRect()?

Tags: javascript

`getClientBoundingRect` is a function that gets a position of element relative to viewport.

Is there a function that is able set value instead?

Comment: I don't think so. You can use position: absolute or fixed and set height/width to simulate the above.

Answer (score 3):

That's what CSS is for. You use CSS to position your elements in the viewport, and since getting the position of an element relative to a viewport and/or other elements is more problematic, you have `getClientBoundingRect` (and a lot of other element-specific DOM API methods).